# Equation of the straight line that passes through the point $(0, 2)$ and has a gradient of $3$

Tags: graphing-functions, quadratics

> Write down the equation of the straight line that passes through the point $(0, 2)$ and has a gradient of $3$.

I need help in writing the equation. Can you help?

Comment: Formula : A line of slope $m$ passing through the point $(a,b)$ has the formula $(y-b) = m(x-a)$. Here the answer would be $(y-2) = 3(x-0)$, giving $y= 3x+2$.

Answer (score 1):

The general equation of a non vertical line is $y=mx+q$ where $m$ is the slope (or gradient) of that line.

If it passes through the point $(0,2)$ then $2=m\cdot 0+q$ which implies that $q=2$. Moroever $m=3$.

Thus your line is $y=3x+2$.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the equation $y=mx+c$ where $m$ is the gradient. Substitute the given values of $x$ and $y$ to get $c=2.$ So the line's equation is $y=3x+2.$